# Get build time of Precompiled Azure Functions assembly during runtime

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

What is the easiest way of getting build time of Precompiled Azure Functions assembly during runtime?

e.g. AssemblyInfo with AssemblyVersion using wildcard does not work with Visual Studio 2017 when doing Azure Functions project.

Displaying the build time would be needed for showing certain people (via HTTP trigger) that deploy has actually done something.

Since it is a Visual Studio 2017 project, the build date could be added to assembly via .csproj modifications, but is this good way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, I assumed that you could add custom attribute in your assembly and read the publish datetime during run-time as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class AssemblyPulishDateTime : Attribute
{
    private readonly long _ticks;

    public DateTime UtcPublishDateTime
    {
        get { return new DateTimeOffset(_ticks, TimeSpan.Zero).UtcDateTime; }
    }

    public AssemblyPulishDateTime(long utcTicks)
    {
        _ticks = utcTicks;
    }
}
```

Then edit `AssemblyInfo.cs` and add the `AssemblyPulishDateTime` with your publish datetime ticks as follows:

```
[assembly: AssemblyPulishDateTime(636354478227030209)] //utc, 7/12/2017 9:17:02 AM
```

For retrieving the publish time during run-time, you could refer to the following code snippet:

```
Assembly assembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
object[] attributes = assembly.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyPulishDateTime), false);
if (attributes.Length == 1)
{
    var attribute = attributes[0] as AssemblyPulishDateTime;
    Console.WriteLine(attribute.UtcPublishDateTime);
}
```